# Using NPM on a Nitrous box setup for Go

Tags: nitrousio

I'm developing a web application in Go on Nitrous.io and i want to install Less for css compilation. Is there a way of installing NPM on a Nitrous box setup for Go development?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't install custom packages into Nitrous boxes (due to the lack of `sudo`), but you can download them via `wget` and run node.js and NPM from the directory folder.

Comment: You can also set the path variable in your `~/.bashrc` file by adding this line at the bottom of the file: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/nodejs`, then type `source ~/.bashrc` back in the terminal. You can now simply type `npm` rather than having to type in the directory of where npm is downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nitrous IDE now include autoparts to manage additional package and nodejs is available:

http://blog.nitrous.io/2013/09/18/introducing-autoparts-for-nitrous-io.html

In the terminal, try:

`parts install nodejs`